# Safe-reading of Python literals

Tags: python, serialization

In short words, I want to know if there is some sort of safe serializer for Python like JSON is for Javascript. I know that Python has a JSON module, but I would like something more python-specific,  with the capability of reading tuples and maybe sets, like this:

```
  [ (3,7), (8,15), (17,21) ]
```

without having to resort to the "eval" function.

Comment: You might want to look at `pickle` module. It can dump and load objects from\to python.

Comment: [ast](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to look at `ast.literal_eval` if you're using 2.6+

```
from ast import literal_eval

s = "[ (3,7), (8,15), (17,21) ]"
t = literal_eval(s)
# [(3, 7), (8, 15), (17, 21)]

type(t)
<type 'list'>
type(t[0])
<type 'tuple'>
```

Or, alternatively look at `pyparsing` and the parsePythonValue.py example on http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 0):

[Use Pickle module](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html). To quote from the documentation:

> Warning The pickle module is not intended to be secure against erroneous or maliciously constructed data. Never unpickle data received from an untrusted or unauthenticated source.

[This article](http://nadiana.com/python-pickle-insecure) is very good about implementing some safety while unpickling (reading from serialised data).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your data to be serialized to a binary format then you can use pickle.
If you want your data to be serialized to a text format then the anwer is no.

If the only distinction that is missing is between lists and tuples (and maybe sets), your best bet might be to use a custom json encoder/decoder. See http://docs.python.org/library/json.html for a few examples.